# How to update embedded documents in mongodb using repository pattern

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

How to use Spring Data Repository to update embedded documents in MongoDB.

```
[{
    "_id": 1,
    "hotel_name": "test_hotel",
    "reviews": [

      {
        "id": 1,
        "rating": "4star",
        "username": "test_user"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "rating": "4star",
        "username": "test_user"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "rating": "4star",
        "username": "test_user"
      }
    ]

  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "hotel_name": "test_hotel2",
    "reviews": [

      {
        "id": 1,
        "rating": "4star",
        "username": "test_user"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "rating": "4star",
        "username": "test_user"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "rating": "4star",
        "username": "test_user"
      }
    ]

  }
]
```

For example, in the above json I want to update 2nd hotel, review id 2. 
Could you please help me how to implement the Repository for this requirement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

using spring stack, you can use SpringData to do it, you just need to implement an interface that extends MongoRepository and do the update using the Update class.

I found a detailed quick start example:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-tutorial